# A script that can check subdiractories for a file that contains 'hello' and gives back directory name

Tags: shell, directory, string

i need a script where you give a directory name as a parameter and the script check all the subdirectories `.php` files and if any file contains a string 'Hello' then the script list the matches files containing directory.

Comment: To avoid sounding like a homework problem (or even a real problem) that you don't want to learn anything from, you can show us what you've tried and how it didn't work. The help center has great tips for helping you ask great questions (and thus great answers -- beyond the two you've already received). http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

With the following you can find all files that contain the string:

```
$ grep -lr Hello directoryname
```

`grep` searches for strings (the name comes from the `g/re/p` you'd use from within the `ed` editor to "g" globally search for the "re" regular expression and "p" print the matching lines).

The `-l` means "list only matching files", normally the filename with the matching line is shown (BTW: if only one file is given its name is normally suppressed).

The `-r` means "search recursively".

Now you have the filenames, you need to strip off the filename as you only want the name of the directory that contain matching files. This can be done by adding a pipeline with `sed` (stream editor):

```
$ grep -lr Hello directoryname | sed 's:/[^/]*$::'
```

The `s` is for `substitute`, and is followed by a match pattern and a replacement text. `[^/]` means "any character, excluding /". The `*` means zero or more of the previous object. The `$` means "match the end of the line". So all non-slash character at the end of the line, *and* the preceding slash (which is the first character in the match pattern) is replaced by an empty string (as the replacement text is empty).

This might leave you with one directory being shown more than once if there is more than one file containing the string being searched for. This can be resolved by extending the pipeline again:

```
$ grep -lr Hello directoryname | sed 's:/[^/]*$::' | uniq
```

`uniq` removes sequentially duplicate lines, leaving you with unique lines (hence the name).

Answer (score 1):

```
find * -prune -type d -exec grep -qm1 'Hello' {}/*.php 2>/dev/null \; -print
```

will select in the current directory from all elements (`*`) just directories (`-type d`) without descending into it (`-prune`) and execute (`-exec`) check (`grep -q`) each ones (`{}`) if they have even one (`-m1`) file `*.php` with word `'Hello'` and `-print` accepted.